# How to get ns records that are registered to ip adress

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, nameserver, nslookup, whois

I have ip ranges.

I would like to find ns addresses that are pointing to corresponding ip adress

I'm looking for a command to do over nslookup or dig

Expected result

http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=70.84.87.146&type=nameserver http://dnsquery.org/nswhois/85.17.137.148

How can I do that over nslookup or dig?

Or are there any solution to have such results

Answer (score 5):

No, you will not easily find such information from dig or any other tool that queries the DNS for a few reasons.

First, NS records do not point at IP addresses, but at DNS names which in turn point to IP addresses.  The distinction is important because the relationship of names to IP addresses is not 1:1, and the reverse of it is rDNS which is not an exact reverse either.  The relationship of IP addresses to names is n:n and it is not guaranteed that the reverse is accurate or complete.  So that part is nontrivial, and requires a complete set of forward lookup information from all the delegation records set to the IP addresses corresponding to them.

Then, there is the question one level before that: how to get a list of all the NS records for all the domains.  Though it is best practice to keep NS records in your domain as well as in the root showing your nameservers, it is not necessarily always the case, but you could probably get a pretty good picture by querying every domain for its NS records.

One level before that is how to get a list of all the domains.  TLD operators will not allow you to transfer their zones as a matter of policy, so this is simply impossible.

The problem here is that, while you can get this information if you have a complete view of the forward lookups (as the reports you saw do), you can't get just a subset of it from the DNS.  The reverse mappings simply do not exist.

Comment: I fear you might not have an approach at all.  I'm not certain how you would get that data, but you cannot reasonably acquire it from the DNS by querying it.